# Delete all files of a resolution Apple Photos

Tags: photos.app

I have recently, imported various photos from both iCloud Shared Album downloads and directly from my iPhone. The problem is that some of these photos are duplicates, however the iCloud Shared Album duplicates are exactly half the resolution.

Duplicate scanners I have tried fail detecting these duplicates because of their different resolution. Additionally, I want to make sure I delete the low-res versions.

Is it possible to batch-delete photos by resolution in Photos.app?

Comment: If anyone can answer Feb 11-12, I'll be willing to offer a +50 bounty to that answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can identify low-resolution photos in *Photos.app* using AppleScript and collate them into a single album that would then allow you to select them all in one go for deletion.

Ordinarily, this code snippet (run from inside *Script Editor*) would find the low-resolution photos (and videos) and put them into a new album called *"Low Res"*:

```
    tell application "Photos" to add ¬
        (every media item whose ¬
            (height > width and height ≤ 480) or ¬
            (width > height and width ≤ 480)) to ¬
        make new album named "Low Res"
```

However, on MacOS 10.13 with the latest updates installed, it throws an error, reporting that it can't retrieve the specified album.  This is probably a bug in *Photos.app*.

So, I decided to assign a description to all of these media items instead:

```
    tell application "Photos" to ¬
        set the description of ¬
            (every media item whose ¬
                (height > width and height ≤ 480) or ¬
                (width > height and width ≤ 480)) to ¬
            "Low Resolution"

    display alert "Done."
```

Then, within *Photos.app*, I created a *Smart Album* with the following search criterion:

[image: Smart Album Criteria in Photos.app on MacOS]

After clicking **OK**, the album was populated by the photos (and videos) that were marked as being of low-resolution.

Now, assuming there's nothing in there you'd like to keep, you would simply press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all of the items, then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> to delete them all from the library (it actually moves them to the library's *Recently Deleted* folder, meaning you can retrieve any items you didn't intend to delete).

#### A couple of notes:

If you don't want video files to be included in the cull, then use these criteria for the smart album instead:

[image: Smart Album Criteria in Photos.app on MacOS to exclude video files]

Note the match selection is set to **all**.  This excludes videos and gives you an album populated only by *photos* of low resolution.

Finally, bear in mind that the AppleScript has to search through your entire library and compare the height and width of every item it comes across.  Depending on your library size, it can take a few minutes.

My *Photos.app* library has 8000 photos in it and it took about three minutes to on a MacBook 1.2GHz m5 to complete.

If *Script Editor* times out, wrap the code inside a `timeout` block and specify a length of time in seconds to allow the code to run to completion:

```
    with timeout of 300 seconds
        tell application "Photos" to...
        ...etc...
    end timeout

    display alert "Done."
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. SE doesn't allow me to bounty the question until Tuesday, but I'll bounty it when it lets me. One odd thing is that my photo library is around 6000 photos and it only took 3 seconds to execute, not sure what could be the cause for this discrepancy.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Re: 3 seconds, I'm clearly using a very underpowered MacBook.

Comment: Started bounty but SE apparently needs me to wait 24hours before rewarding it

Comment: Changing `every media item whose (height > width and height ≤ 480) or (width > height and width ≤ 480)` into `get media item whose (height > width and height ≤ 480) or (width > height and width ≤ 480)` will work. `get` must be used explicitly here.

Comment: @lzx Given that it worked fine for a good few years, and possibly still does (I haven't checked recently), why do you think that `get` is required? I can tell you why it shouldn't be used, particularly in the second code block, so I'm curious what you understand about the purpose of `get`? [ **PS.** You omitted either the word `every` or the plural form of the `media item` class. ]